# MediaPlayer и синхронизация

Tags: android, java

У меня два вопроса:

1. В каком потоке выполняется объект `MediaPlayer`.
2. Нужна ли синхронизация его методов, если я управляю плеером только из основного потока?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В отдельном
2. Не нужна